# how to check what code is preventing a node process to quit?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a couple of libraries, one of which is likely preventing the node process from quitting. i.e.: some unclosed streams, connections, etc.

Is there a generic way to inspect what is preventing node to quit? *

Thanks.

- ) Presumably a way to look at the javascript command stack or something?

Comment: downvotes. Please explain why.

Comment: Please, write details: code, names of libs... We are not prophets

Comment: perhaps it was not clear, but I was asking for a generic way to approach this. I.e.: looking which commands are still lingering on the javascript command stack

Comment: So, you need a stacktrace? `console.log(new Error().stack)` shows your current stack in current line of code. Or catch the errors with [`domains`](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_domain)

Comment: @MiKeBu: Those could be valid approaches. Next time, may I suggest reading my entire question, before casting a negative vote with an elitist air. You're new to this community. We're generally a friendly bunch.

Comment: I'm not voted yet, but i can do this. Real downvoters had ignored you. Good luck)

Comment: Have you tried playing around with [`node-inspector`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector)? start your script with debug and have the node inspector running. After it is supposed to be done, press the pause button and see where the debugger leads you.

Comment: @MiKeBu Write it as an answer that is acceptable for this question.